# Searching multiple tables with postgreSQL 13 and Rails 6+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search

I provide a lot of context to set the stage for the question. What I'm trying to solve is fast and accurate fuzzysearch against multiple database tables using structured data, not full-text document search.

I'm using postgreSQL 13.4+ and Rails 6+ if it matters.

I have fairly structured data for several tables:

```
class Contact
  attribute :id
  attribute :first_name
  attribute :last_name
  attribute :email
  attribute :phone
end

class Organization
  attribute :name
  attribute :license_number
end

...several other tables...
```

I'm trying to implement a fast and accurate fuzzysearch so that I can search across all these tables (Rails models) at once.

Currently I have a separate search query using `ILIKE` that concats the columns I want to search against on-the-fly for each model:

```
# contact.rb
scope :search -> (q) { where("concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, email, phone) ILIKE :q", q: "%#{q}%") 

# organization.rb
scope :search -> (q) { where("concat_ws(' ', name, license_number) ILIKE :q", q: "%#{q}%") }
```

In my search controller I query each of these tables separately and display the top 3 results for each model.

```
@contacts = Contact.search(params[:q]).limit(3)
@organizations = Organization.search(params[:q]).limit(3)
```

This *works* but is fairly slow and not as accurate as I would like.

Problems with my current approach:

1. Slow (relatively speaking) with only thousands of records.
2. Not accurate because `ILIKE` must have an exact match somewhere in the string and I want to implement fuzzysearch (ie, with `ILIKE`, "smth" would not match "smith").
3. Not weighted; I would like to weight the `contacts.last_name` column over say the `organizations.name` because the contacts table is generally speaking the higher priority search item.

## My solution

My theoretical solution is to create a `search_entries` polymorphic table that has a separate record for each `contact`, `organization`, etc, that I want to search against, and then this `search_entries` table could be indexed for fast retrieval.

```
class SearchEntry
  attribute :data
  belongs_to :searchable, polymorphic: true

  # Store data as all lowercase to optimize search (avoid lower method in PG)
  def data=(text)
    self[:data] = text.lowercase
  end
end
```

However, what I'm getting stuck on is how to structure this table so that it can be indexed and searched quickly.

```
contact = Contact.first
SearchEntry.create(searchable: contact, data: "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name} #{contact.email} #{contact.phone}")

organization = Organization.first
SearchEntry.create(searchable: organization, data: "#{organization.name} #{organization.license_number}")
```

This gives me the ability to do something like:

`SearchEntry.where("data LIKE :q", q: "%#{q}%")`

or even something like fuzzysearch using PG's `similarity()` function:

`SearchEntry.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM search_entries ORDER BY SIMILARITY(data, '#{q}') LIMIT 10")`

I believe I can use a `GIN` index with `pg_trgm` on this `data` field as well to optimize searching (not 100% on that...).

This simplifies my search into a single query on a single table, but it still doesn't allow me to do weighted column searching (ie, `contacts.last_name` is more important than `organizations.name`).

## Questions

1. Would this approach enable me to index the data so that I could have very fast fuzzysearch? (I know "very fast" is subjective, so what I mean is an efficient usage of PG to get results as quickly as possible).
2. Would I be able to use a `GIN` index combined with `pg_trgm` tri-grams to index this data for fast fuzzysearch?
3. How would I implement weighting certain values higher than others in an approach like this?

Comment: There is a tool to do exactly that https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Comment: Have you considered if you might be better off using and OFS search solution like Solr, Lucene or ElasticSearch?

Comment: @max: I have looked at ElasticSearch as my fallback if it isn't possible to get what I need in PG itself. I'm trying to reduce dependencies both for cost and complexity by keeping it all within the database.

Comment: @AhmedKamal: I'm trying to avoid external dependencies at the moment, but if accomplishing search within PG isn't going to work like I need, I would look at ElasticSearch since I have a little more familiarity with it.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to create a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html) consisting of a union of data from the two (or more tables). Take this simplefied example:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW searchables AS
  SELECT
    resource_id,
    resource_type,
    name,
    weight
  FROM 
    SELECT 
      id as resource_id,
      'Contact' as resource_type
      concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) AS name,
      1 AS weight
    FROM contacts
    UNION
    SELECT 
      id as resource_id,
      'Organization' as resource_type
      name
      2 AS weight 
    FROM organizations
```

```
class Searchable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true

  def readonly?
    true
  end

  # Search contacts and organziations with a higher weight on contacts
  def self.search(name)
    where(arel_table[:name].matches(name)).order(weight: :desc)
  end
end
```

Since materialized views are stored in a table like structure you can apply indices just like you could with a normal table:

```
CREATE INDEX searchables_name_trgm ON name USING gist (searchables gist_trgm_ops);
```

To ActiveRecord it also behaves just like a normal table.

Of course the complexity here will grow with number of columns you want to search and the end result might end up both underwhelming in functionality and overwhelming in complexity compared to an off the shelf solution with thousands of hours behind it.

The scenic gem can be used to make the migrations for creating materialized views simpler.